# Javascript Redirect Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have the below code in a HTML page on my site.  The url parameter is loading fine on a pixel fire right above it but for some reason the redirect doesn't want to fire.  Anyone have any ideas?  It might be an IE issue but not sure.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setInterval("window.location = '{{$url}}'", 4000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you can only pass functions to `setInterval`.

Comment: Actually, I just tested this on IE7 and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = '...';
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setInterval(function() {
                 window.location.href = url;
                 }, 4000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: No need to use jQuery for this, or indeed to wait for the DOM to be ready.